# Ошибка в функции с переменным числом параметров

Tags: c++, c

Пытаюсь написать создание по формату `std::string` с помощью `vsnprintf`, но что-то где-то пошло не так и программа падает во время вызова `vsnprintf`.

```
inline std::string makeString(const char * pFormat, va_list vaList)
{
    int nLength = strlen(pFormat) * 2;

    std::unique_ptr<char[]> pFormatted;
    while (true)
    {
        pFormatted.reset(new char[nLength]);

        int nFormattedLength;
        va_start(vaList, pFormat);
        nFormattedLength = vsnprintf(pFormatted.get(), nLength, pFormat, vaList);
        va_end(vaList);

        if (nFormattedLength < 0 || nFormattedLength >= nLength)
            nLength += std::abs(nFormattedLength - nLength + 1);
        else
            break;
    }

    return std::string(pFormatted.get());
}

inline std::string makeString(const char * pFormat, ...)
{
    va_list vaList;
    std::string result;

    va_start(vaList, pFormat);
    result = makeString(pFormat, vaList);
    va_end(vaList);

    return std::move(result);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << makeString("testing %d %s %d\n", 58, "ggg", 76) << std::endl;
}
```

По логике ошибка где-то в перевыделении памяти, поскольку следующий код работает корректно, но где именно - понять не могу

```
void test(const char * pFormat, ...)
{
    va_list vaList;
    char arr[1024];
    va_start(vaList, pFormat);
    vsnprintf(arr, 1024, pFormat, vaList);
    va_end(vaList);

    printf("%s", arr);
}

int main()
{
    test("testing %d %s %d\n", 58, "ggg", 76);
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы снова делаете `va_start` внутри верхнего `makeString`??? Вы же его уже сделали в нижнем `makeString`.

Comment: Отдельно не ясно, зачем понадобилось вот это `nLength += std::abs(nFormattedLength - nLength + 1);` если можно просто `nLength = nFormattedLength + 1;`

Comment: Это первый опыт с шаманствами с `va_list`, поэтому допустил ошибку думая, что `va_start/va_end` локальны для каждой из функций. Если убрать второй вызов, то все работает. Спасибо. Прошу оформить как ответ

Comment: Его так же не стоит делать в цикле, тут весь смак в том что вы используете его как сквозной параметр, а следовательно реинициализировать его не нужно. Кстати в posix  традиционно первая версия функции имела префикс v, например  vfprintf.

Comment: Вообще, эта функция (vsnprintf) не varargs как таковая. И туда удобней всего передавать указатель на структуру, приводя его к (void*). Хотя это на любителя. Но так более читабельно получается. главное - чтобы типы в структуре соответствовали указанным в шаблоне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся идея подхода с передачей `va_list` в дополнительную функцию заключается в том, что `va_start` для этого `va_list` делается именно и только в вызывающей функции, а во внутренней функции его делать не надо - туда приходит уже "стартовавший" `va_list`.

У вас во второй `makeString` правильно делается `va_start`, а затем внутри первой `makeString` снова делается `va_start`. Повторный `va_start` не нужен.